# From Where can I edit my source code on Wix website?

Tags: velo

I have submitted a listing for my website on a different website and for the verification, I have to add the code in my body section. But as a beginner, I don't have even knowledge that from where I can remove the verification code from my backend because I have to remove it myself without the help of the developer.

Can anyone help me resolve my query regarding my small concern?

I was expecting that I can remove it without aby help but right now I am seeking for help